# convexityDefects wrong output (not enough defects!)

Tags: python, opencv

I am dealing with a problem about circle detection and I have reached some merged structures like the next one (hope it doesn't lose quality) :

https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2020/4/17/6c447e49890278d40c9a44d109772b87-full.png

My idea has been to find these intersection points by first using hullConvex function in order to look for the convex envelope and then use convexityDefects in order to find the convex points as defects. Nevertheless, the convexityDefects seems to fail, since I get this:

https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2020/4/17/1ab59bfaaaa5a2e6f4e054dfd798d301-full.png

Here we've the original-contour in yellow, the hull-contour in blue and the defects that the model has found in red.

The non-intersecting points are easily removed by filtering by the deep of the defect, but I miss the two upper intersection points. And I do really think they should theoritecally appear. I share here my code:

```
def roi_contour(roi):
    drawing = np.zeros((roi.shape[0], roi.shape[1], 3), np.uint8)
    cntsSorted, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(roi, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    #cntsSorted = sorted(sub_cb, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x),reverse=True)
    hull = []
    for i_x in range(len(cntsSorted)):
        hull.append(cv2.convexHull(cntsSorted[i_x]))
    cv2.drawContours(drawing, cntsSorted, 0, (255, 255, 255), -1, 8, hierarchy)
    cv2.drawContours(drawing, cntsSorted, 0, (0, 255, 255), 2, 8, hierarchy)
    cv2.drawContours(drawing, hull, 0, (255,0,0), 2, 8, hierarchy)
    cnt = cntsSorted[0]
    env = cv2.convexHull(cnt,returnPoints = False)
    defectos = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt,env)
    points_def = []
    try:
        for k in range(defectos.shape[0]):
            i,f,l,d = defectos[k,0]
            maslejano = tuple(cnt[l][0])
            #if d>6000:
            points_def.append(maslejano)
            cv2.circle(drawing,maslejano,3,[0,0,255],-1)
    except:
        pass
```

I have even thought about the possibility that they are mathematically non-convex, but I am pretty sure (especially cause the lower ones are almost equal) that this is not the problem...

Do I have some misunderstanding with this function or is it an openCV's library failure?

Thanks a lot for your help, mates!

Comment: See: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html

Comment: Already tried, but it is not what I was asking for. Thanks anyway!